# Reread a response body from JavaScript's fetch

Tags: javascript, json, stream, httpresponse, fetch-api

`fetch()` returns promise which (if successful) resolves to a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object. A very common thing to do is immediately call [`Response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) to convert the response body to a JSON object.

If the response body isn't valid JSON, then the `Response.json()` promise fails with an error. The message is something along the lines of:

> Unexpected token X in JSON at position 0

That's not very helpful when trying to diagnose the problem; ideally I'd like to be able to see the content from the server (which is often an error message).

However, it appears that you can only read the stream at `Response.body` once (at least in Chrome). (There's even a read-only [`Response.bodyUsed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/bodyUsed) flag.) That has already happened when `Response.json()` tries to convert the body to JSON, so the body appears to be lost forever in the event of a JSON parsing failure.

Is there any way to recover the original response body... short of manually reading it (and then converting to JSON) when the original `fetch` Promise resolves?

Comment: You could call `response.text()` instead to read the returned data even if it's not valid JSON, and you can clone a response, but ideally your server should **always** return JSON when you expect JSON, even the errors should be returned as JSON.

Comment: **See Also**: [Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53511974/1366033)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use [`Response.clone()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/clone) to clone `Response`

```
let clone = response.clone();
```

Alternatively, use `Response.body.getReader()` which returns a `ReadableStream` to read `Response` as a stream, `TextDecoder()` to convert `Uint8Array` data stream to text.

Comment: @CraigWalker See [How can I append DOM elements as they stream in from the network?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413400/how-can-i-append-dom-elements-as-they-stream-in-from-the-network/)

Comment: clone() looked like the answer, but it fails if you've already called .json(): "TypeError: Failed to execute 'clone' on 'Response': Response body is already used"

So resp.text() followed by manual json parsing is one option, but +1 for Jaromanda's suggestion to clone() before calling json()!

Comment: @xander Yes, `.clone()` needs to be called before `body` is read. This is why `javascript` at Answer is `response.clone()`. Have you read the specification https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#body-mixin, https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#bodies, https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-response-clone ?

Comment: I'm getting `Failed to execute 'clone' on 'Response': Response body is already used`

Comment: @Pacerier Then `Response.body` has already been used at the code. Can you create a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net or plnkr https://plnkr.co to demonstrate?

Comment: thanks @guest271314 for the answer , here is a working example if any one needed more help https://codesandbox.io/s/parcel-sandbox-5sy2h

Answer (score 13):

I had to deal with an API that occasionally botched the JSON response - before returning `response.json()` I made a clone of the response object. using a catch block, I can determine if the error is a SyntaxError, and proceed to fix the error using the text result of the response clone

a little like this:

```
var brokenJson = function (url) {
    var responseCopy;
    return fetch(url)
    .then(function (response) {
        responseCopy = response.clone();
        return response.json();
    }).catch(function (err) {
        if (err instanceof SyntaxError) {
            return responseCopy.text()
            .then(function(data) {
                return fixJson(data);
            });
        }
        else {
            throw err;
        }
    }).then(function (json) {
        // do things
    });
};
```

`fixJson` is just a function that fixes the received data - in my case, when it was broken JSON, it was always broken the same way - I think it had an extra leading { or trailing } - can't recall

re-reading the question, you're more likely to want to log the error to the console rather than fix the json - easy rewrite:

```
var brokenJson = function (url) {
    var responseCopy;
    return fetch(url)
    .then(function (response) {
        responseCopy = response.clone();
        return response.json();
    }).catch(function (err) {
        if (err instanceof SyntaxError) {
            return responseCopy.text()
            .then(function(text) {
                console.error(text);
                throw err;
            });
        }
        else {
            throw err;
        }
    }).then(function (json) {
        // do things
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the response.json() to a variable and returning it worked for me. clone() was again saying its locked.

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/watchlist")
    .then(response => {
      var res = response.json();
      return res;
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({ data });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `JSON.parse(response.resp.data)` as somehow clone didn't work.