# Intercept fetch() API requests and responses in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, interceptor, fetch-api

I want to intercept fetch API requests and responses in JavaScript.

For example, before sending the request I want to intercept the request URL. I'd like to intercept the response once it arrives as well.

The below code is for intercepting responses of all `XMLHTTPRequest`s.

```
(function(open) {
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(XMLHttpRequest) {
    var self = this;
    this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
      if (this.responseText.length > 0 && 
          this.readyState == 4 && 
          this.responseURL.indexOf('www.google.com') >= 0) {

        Object.defineProperty(self, 'response', {
          get: function() { return bValue; },
          set: function(newValue) { bValue = newValue; },
          enumerable: true,
          configurable: true
        });
        self.response = 'updated value' // Intercepted Value 
      }
    }, false);
    open.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

I want to implement the same feature for `fetch()` API. How can I do this?

Comment: Sounds like you want hack into the Window.Request interface https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#request https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request to do something similar to what you did in the code example in the question. I personally can’t offer any more specific guidance then saying that’s where you’d probably want to start experimenting

Comment: Is there any way to detect all success callback of fetch API call?. 
For ex:
   $(document).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
   });

Comment: The only means you have for checking the response status is to check the `ok` attribute of the response object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok: `fetch(someURL).then(function(response) { if(response.ok) { /* do something */}`

Comment: Thank you @sidehowbarker..
I want to add the success call back for all fetch request in the site. I am going to run my code top of the application.I don't know how many fetch request register in the application based on the request URL in the call back i need to execute some functionality.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For intercepting the fetch request and parameter we can go for below mentioned way. its resolved my issue.

```
 const constantMock = window.fetch;
 window.fetch = function() {
     // Get the parameter in arguments
     // Intercept the parameter here 
    return constantMock.apply(this, arguments)
 }
```

Comment: How to use this code. do we need to call constantMock after this code?

Comment: just call the fetch API a regular way.  we already defined our own fetch so the call will be intercepted in our function definition.

Comment: is it fetch all browser API? elaborate my application loaded with SSO(OKTA), wanna change one api response, is it possible?

Comment: yes. it will intercept all the fetch API. but you can have condition check inside the function based on you can do the manipulation.  just console log the arguments and this object, you can see all the values

Answer (score 81):

Existing answers show the general structure for mocking `fetch` in the browser but omit important details.

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45889043/6243352) shows the general pattern for replacing the `window.fetch` function with custom implementation that intercepts the call and forwards the arguments to `fetch`. However, the pattern shown doesn't let the interception function do anything with the response (for example, read the status or body or inject a mock) so is only useful for logging request parameters. This is a pretty narrow use case.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54068920/6243352) uses an `async` function to let the interceptor `await` on the `fetch` promise and presumably work with the response (mocking, reading, etc) but (at the time of writing) has a superfluous closure and doesn't show how to read the response body non-destructively. It also contains a variable aliasing bug leading to a stack overflow.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53448336/6243352) is the most complete so far but has some irrelevant noise in the callback and doesn't mention anything about cloning the response to enable the body to be collected by the interceptor. It doesn't illustrate how a mock could be returned.

Here's a minimal, complete example that rectifies these issues, showing how to handle parameter logging, reading the body without harming the original caller [by cloning the response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40497917/6243352) and (optionally) providing a mock response.

```js
const {fetch: origFetch} = window;
window.fetch = async (...args) => {
  console.log("fetch called with args:", args);
  const response = await origFetch(...args);

  /* work with the cloned response in a separate promise
     chain -- could use the same chain with `await`. */
  response
    .clone()
    .json()
    .then(data => console.log("intercepted response data:", data))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

  /* the original response can be resolved unmodified: */
  //return response;

  /* or mock the response: */
  return new Response(JSON.stringify({
    userId: 1,
    id: 1,
    title: "Mocked!!",
    completed: false
  }));
};

// test it out with a typical fetch call
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log("original caller received:", data))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: This is the best answer for stability

Comment: why do we need async while returning json in response object?

Comment: We don't. It's there to maintain consistency with the original fetch API, where `response.json()` returns a promise.

Comment: Is there any specific permission required to run this code as part of a browser extension? For some reason my code just stop running at  the call to origFetch, but return no error or warning in the console or browser console.

Comment: @FMaz008 I don't think so. I would post a new question, with a [mcve] and full details of your problem.

Comment: Works fine in  Chrome, just not in Firefox for some odd reasons.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, it works fine if ran in the main world/environment. It only not work on Firefox if ran under the content_scripts of a browser extension, but if the code is injected in the main world, it works fine there (but won't intercept the extension calls)

Comment: @FMaz008 Again, I suggest asking a new question. I don't know the answer offhand or have your extension code that I can run and examine, and it's out of scope of the current question. None of the code here is Chrome-specific that I'm aware of. If you do find an answer, feel free to drop a comment here, especially if there's a simple adjustment I can make to this to support the behavior you want.

Comment: I found one bit lacking, second parameter to Response: `return new Response(JSON.stringify({...}), response);`. Without this I was getting invalid responses that resulted in crashes when sent back to the frontend.

Comment: @mkey Are you sure that isn't a problem specific to your application? What browser are you using and what error did you see? According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response#options), the second parameter to the `Response` constructor is optional. And if you do provide it, it's "An options object containing any custom settings that you want to apply to the response, or an empty object (which is the default value). The possible options are: `status`, `statusText` and `headers`", which I guess a `response` object will fulfill if it isn't typed.

Comment: @ggorlen the browser in question is a current chrome version, whichever that is. For the exact error I would have to recheck. That script is being used on my work laptop to extend functionality of YouTrack. They switched over to FETCH recently.

Comment: @mkey Thanks. I suggest opening a new question with the error and reproducible details. Feel free to @ me when/if you do so I can see if I need to make any adjustments here.

Answer (score 27):

For intercepting the response body you need to create a new Promise and resolve or reject current into "then" code. It solved for me and keep content for real app, e.g. React, etc.

```js
const constantMock = window.fetch;
window.fetch = function() {
  console.log(arguments);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    constantMock
      .apply(this, arguments)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.url.indexOf("/me") > -1 &&
            response.type != "cors") {
          console.log(response);
          // do something for specificconditions
        }
        resolve(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
      })
  });
}
```

Comment: Just want to add a detail: if you need the response body to "do something for specific conditions", do not forget to clone the response, otherwise, the final user of the promise will get "TypeError: Body has already been consumed". So, do like "response.clone().json()" or "response.clone().text()" to get the body.

Answer (score 18):

```js
const fetch = window.fetch;
window.fetch = (...args) => (async(args) => {
    var result = await fetch(...args);
    console.log(result); // intercept response here
    return result;
})(args);
```

Comment: This blows the stack in Chrome 83.0. `const origFetch = window.fetch` and `await origFetch(...args)` fixes the problem. Also, I'm not sure why the outermost function exists. You can just use `fetch = async (...args) => ...` and skip the IIFE.

Answer (score 2):

Further to Hariharan's answer, Here is how I updated spinner state in Redux before and after each fetch request

```
import store from './../store';

// Set up interceptor on all fetch API calls
// Increments redux spinner state when api is called
// Decrements redux spinner state again when it is returned
(function() {
    const originalFetch = window.fetch;
    window.fetch = function() {
        store.dispatch({type: 'show-spinner'})
        return originalFetch.apply(this, arguments)
            .then((res) => {
                store.dispatch({type: 'hide-spinner'})
                return res;
            })
    }
})();
```