# Greasemonkey: one more what is the concept of intercepting/modifying fetch requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch, response, greasemonkey

I've dug all the questions here, and, to proove the concept, what I've understood that if I want to catch a response from a request call - I have to alter the function that website implements. As I am not a front-ender, I do not quite understand the way it should be done...

I have the following code in Greasemonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    let originalFetch = unsafeWindow.fetch;
    console.log(originalFetch);   //*1
  
    unsafeWindow.fetch = function monitorFetch (x, y){
        let response = originalFetch(x, y);
        let respo = response.clone();
        return response;
    };
  
    console.log(unsafeWindow.fetch);   //*2
```

The console from `*1` prints

`function monitorFetch (x, y)`

and the console from `*2` also prints

`function monitorFetch (x, y)`

But the website with this altering is not working - no thrown errors, I just see that requests that should be made are not being made.

I have also tried to find this original `monitorFetch` function in website javascript and copy-paste it into Greasemonkey - the same result: no errors, no requests made.

What I want - is just to catch the response, I don't even need to modify anything.

**Question**: what am I not understanding, or doing wrong, or not doing?

Versions: `Greasemonkey v4.11` `Firefox v81`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intercept fetch() API requests and responses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425169/intercept-fetch-api-requests-and-responses-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.

In general - the question remains.

But as for this particular case of mine - I was lucky: the website saves the data I am looking for in unsafeWindow.`localStorage`.