# Playwright API testing: intercept API request

Tags: typescript, playwright, web-api-testing, playwright-test

I'm testing a server with [Playwright's API testing](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-api-testing#writing-api-test).

I have a simple `GET` route, that always returns a 405 not allowed. It also logs that the API route was called. For the sake of this StackOverflow example, I replaced the log with a `fetch` to a place holder API.

```
export const loader = async () => {
  await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
  return notAllowed();
};
```

In my API test, I want to intercept the `fetch` request to the placeholder API, and just verify that it was called, without actually calling it.

When you write a normal browser test with Playwright, you can use `page.route`:

```
page.route('*', route => {
  console.log('url', route.request().url());
  route.continue();
});
```

However, because this is an API test and doesn't run in a page, this won't work.

How can I intercept the API request to make assertions on it?

I tried creating a new context with:

```
test('my test', async ({ playwright }) => {
  const context = await playwright.request.context();
});
```

but that `context` object, is actually a `request` object, so you can't run `request.on`. I also tried using the `context` argument from the default fixture, but it also doesn't work.

Comment: Possibly changing the default fetch function? [Intercept fetch() API requests and responses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425169/intercept-fetch-api-requests-and-responses-in-javascript)

Comment: Have you considered using a proxy? This seems a bit complicated for a relatively simple need, but maybe this is acceptable to you?