# Intercept fetch() doesn't capture all fetch calls

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, monkeypatching

I followed the answer here: [Intercept fetch() API requests and responses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425169/intercept-fetch-api-requests-and-responses-in-javascript)

**inject.js**

```
const { fetch: origFetch } = window;
window.fetch = async (...args) => {
  window.postMessage({ type: 'API_AJAX_CALL', payload: args }, '*');
  const response = await origFetch(...args);
  return response;
};
```

**content_script.js**

```
var headElement = (document.head || document.documentElement);
var injectJs = function (fileName) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = chrome.extension.getURL(fileName);
    headElement.insertBefore(s, headElement.firstElementChild);
};

// Register to receive the message from the injected script
window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "API_AJAX_CALL")) {
        console.log("CONTENT-SCRIPT-CONTEXT: Received the data " + event.data.payload[0]);
    }
}, false);

injectJs("inject.js");
```

**manifest**

```
  "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*/*"],
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "run_at": "document_start",
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ],
```

but the patched api only captures some of the fetch calls (marked with green circles - injected content script). It even misses the fetch calls which happened after few of the fetch calls were captured.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are limits to this sort of thing. Here's a probably-incomplete list of calls you can't intercept as shown:

- Calls that started before your script was run
- Calls where the code captured `fetch` to a local before your script was run (unlikely, but...):

  ```
  (() => { const myFetch = fetch; /*...code using `myFetch`...*/ })();
  ```
- Calls made by [service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)

You can only do what you can do. You might want to look at various `webRequest` events such as [`onBeforeRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insights. Service workers idea seems promising. I will explore that.