# userscript failing to intercept most requests

Tags: javascript, browser, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I have this userscript for [duolingo.com](https://duolingo.com) that used to intercept and log every network request url, but no longer does. Now it only logs a few requests and nothing else.

Here's the script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         MyScript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.duolingo.com/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=duolingo.com
// @grant        GM_log
// ==/UserScript==

(function(send, open) {
    'use strict';

    console.log('RUNNING');

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = async function(body) {
        console.log('send() called on', this.url);
        send.apply(this, [body]);
    };

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url) {
        console.log('open() called on', url);
        this.url = url;
        open.apply(this, arguments);
    };

})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send, XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

And here are the logs:

```
RUNNING
open() called on https://d35aaqx5ub95lt.cloudfront.net/sounds/0a27c1ee63dd220647e8410a0029aed2.mp3
send() called on https://d35aaqx5ub95lt.cloudfront.net/sounds/0a27c1ee63dd220647e8410a0029aed2.mp3
open() called on https://api.rollbar.com:443/api/1/item/
send() called on https://api.rollbar.com:443/api/1/item/
open() called on https://excess.duolingo.com/batch
send() called on https://excess.duolingo.com/batch
open() called on https://excess.duolingo.com/batch
send() called on https://excess.duolingo.com/batch
open() called on https://excess.duolingo.com/batch
send() called on https://excess.duolingo.com/batch
open() called on https://excess.duolingo.com/batch
send() called on https://excess.duolingo.com/batch
```

I know by inspecting the network tab that there are certain requests that are supposed to get intercepted but don't, for instance the `https://www.duolingo.com/YYYY-MM-DD/sessions` request, which I can see in the network tab but doesn't get logged to the console.

The match pattern is obviously correct (otherwise none of the logs would be showing), and I know for a fact the script used to work.

Adding `@run-at document-start` in the metadata improves things slightly, allowing me to see the logs for more requests, but still not nearly for all of them.

I've also tried overriding `window.fetch` as shown below, but that way none of the URLs would get logged:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    console.log('SCRIPT IS RUNNING');

    const originalFetch = window.fetch;

    window.fetch = async function(request, options) {
        console.log(request.url);
        return originalFetch.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})();
```

Comment: Perhaps the request is made early? Try including `// @run-at document-start` in the userscript metadata.

Comment: @double-beep yes, I have tried this as well. It improves slightly (I see a couple more requests), but still not solved completely.

Comment: Try: [Intercept `fetch()` API requests and responses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45425169) as the request to `/date/sessions` is a `fetch`, not an `xhr` request.

Comment: Just tried this, but it didn't work. I'm pretty sure this is the same as what I have at the end of my answer. 

I'm not sure how you concluded that `/sessions` is a fetch, but one of its headers in the network tab reads `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`. Although I'm no expert as to what this means.

Comment: @double-beep UPDATE: tried it again but with `unsafeWindow` instead of `window`, and it seems to log out everything now

Comment: Inspect the initiator of that request in devtools and see how it's made by the site.