# JavaScript fetch - Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream is locked

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

When the request status is greater than 400(I have tried 400, 423, 429 states), fetch cannot read the returned json content. The following error is displayed in the browser console

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'json' on
>   'Response': body stream is locked

I showed the contents of the returned response object as follows:

[image]

But I can still use it a few months ago.

My question is as follows:

- Is this just the behavior of the Chrome browser or the fetch standard changes?
- Is there any way to get the body content of these states?

PS: My browser version is Google Chrome 70.0.3538.102（正式版本） （64 位）

Comment: This means you are getting a response from api, but its not a valid json, are you sending all required parameters in the request?

Comment: @kiranvj I verified my data, the same content, I just changed the status code to 200 to get it correctly.

Comment: I have the same problem but my status is 200, how did you solved it eventually?

Comment: @DavSev For a specific status code, I get the return data through axios

Comment: it happens with 200, too.

Comment: `response.json()` **should** work, but there's a group of methods that can only be **called once**. So try to fiddle with what you do before the failing line. In my case the issue was the line `if (response.status == 200)`, which had to be replaced with `if (response.ok)`

Comment: luna, you should consider accepting Criss Anger's answer

Comment: @KyleMit I think everyone's answer solves the "how do I get data" problem. But I don’t think anyone’s answer can tell me: Why is it prompted me that the data has been read when I read the data for the first time, so I didn’t choose anyone’s answer. I hope someone can explain this problem, thanks

Comment: @Luna `Why is it prompted me that the data has been read when I read the data for the first time`, basically, _something_ has (at very least) acquired a lock for the stream (using `getReader`), perhaps somewhere in a framework or library that you are using. Look thoroughly through all your source, and included libraries, for uses of `getReader` or [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#body_interface_methods) methods.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

According to MDN, you should use [`Response.clone()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/clone):

> The `clone()` method of the [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) interface creates a clone of a response object, identical in every way, but stored in a different variable.   The main reason `clone()` exists is to allow multiple uses of [`Body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body) objects (when they are one-use only.)

**Example**:

```
fetch('yourfile.json').then(res=>res.clone().json())
```

Comment: This worked great for me, but anyone understand why this is necessary?

i looked it up, and I see that sometimes once a reader starts reading the `Response.body`, it gets locked to that reader.  But from what I can see (at least in my code), nothing has ever started reading... is there an explanation of how the readable stream could get automatically locked?

Comment: I had the same issue but found out that I had "res.json()" in my watch panel in chrome dev tools, which was being resolved before the code itself!

Comment: wait, what? @FelipeDrumond thats a crazy (non) bug!

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Well, if we can only run response.json() once and your chrome dev tools watch panel runs that before your code, you'll have an exception because well, you ran response.json() twice!

Comment: Reference [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/clone)

Comment: Unsure if this has changed since 2019, but now calling `Response.clone()` in the original question scenario (when `Response.body.locked` is `true`) throws a `TypeError` (e.g `TypeError: Response.clone: Body has already been consumed.`). As per MDN: `clone() throws a TypeError if the response Body has already been used`

Comment: @jenming This is due to the way the HTTP protocol works. It is not a classic data, it is a data stream. When the data stream (readableStream) is consumed, it is then emptied. That's why the error occurs.

Answer (score 275):

I met this error too but found out it is not related to the state of Response, the real problem is that you only can consume `Response.json()` once, if you are consuming it more than once, the error will happen.

like below:

```
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/movies').then(response =>{
    console.log(response);
    if(response.ok){
         console.log(response.json()); //first consume it in console.log
        return response.json(); //then consume it again, the error happens

    }
```

So the solution is to avoid consuming `Response.json()` more than once in `then` block.

Comment: you could `response.clone()` before consuming it.

Comment: Nice. i had a `console.log(r.json()); return r.json();` which broke it.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve the result if I called it and forgot to store it?

Comment: You could get the text first using response.text() and then use JSON.parse(text) but that defeats the purpose of response.json(). `var text = await response.text(); let data = JSON.parse(text);`

Answer (score 13):

Response methode like 'json', 'text' can be called once, and then it locks.
The posted image of response shows that body is locked.
This means you have already called the 'then', 'catch'. To reslove this you can try the following.

```
fetch(url)
    .then(response=> response.body.json())
    .then(myJson=> console.log(myJson))
```

Or

```
fetch(url)
    .catch(response=> response.body.json())
    .catch(myJson=> console.log(myJson))
```

Answer (score 12):

I know it's too late but it can help someone:

```
let response = await fetch(targetUrl);
let data = await response.json();
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed to resolve this matter using async/await syntax, thank you!

Comment: If response is not in JSON format, you'll be locked

Comment: but where is the clone method here? wirtting it like this i still get the same error message

Comment: @AlexanderMatveev You can use `var text = await response.text(); let data = JSON.parse(text);`

Answer (score 4):

I was accidentally reusing a response object, something similar to this:

```
const response = await new ReleasePresetStore().findAll();
const json = await response.json();
this.setState({ releasePresets: json });

const response2 = await new ReleasePresetStore().findActive();
const json2 = await response.json();
this.setState({ active: json2 });
console.log(json2);
```

This line:

```
const json2 = await response.json();
```

Should have been (response2 instead of the used up response1):

```
const json2 = await response2.json();
```

Reusing the previous response made no sense and it was a dirty code typo...

Answer (score 4):

I also stuck into this. But this worked for me.

```
fetch(YOUR_URL)
.then(res => {
  try {
    if (res.ok) {
      return res.json()
    } else {
      throw new Error(res)
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
    return WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TO_RETURN
  }
})
.then (resJson => {
  return resJson.data
})
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

good luck

Comment: An example about fetch in MDN https://github.com/mdn/fetch-examples/blob/master/fetch-json/index.html#L25

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```js
response.json().then(data => {
  // use data
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
fetch("xxxxxxxxxx")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => { console.log(data)})
.catch(error => { console.log(error)})
```

Answer (score 2):

I keep getting the same error even after [cloning the response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54115314/2516673). None of the answers cover the case when you need to fallback to text in case the response data is not a JSON.

In my case, the error was being thrown because first I was trying to consume the response data as a JSON, then consuming the text if the response isn't a valid JSON.

```js
// Consuming the response data multiple times throws an error.
const response = await fetch(url, request);
try {
  return await response.json();
} catch (error) {
  return await response.text();
}
```

With the help of some of the answers, I'm now consuming the response data only once, as plain text, then try to parse it to JSON.

```js
// This works fine because the data is being consumed only once.
const response = await fetch(url, request);
const data = await response.text();
try {
  return JSON.parse(data);
} catch (error) {
  console.warn(`API response is not JSON. Falling back to plain text.`, error);
  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the question when you're trying to use same response object, your body is about to locked due to state of the object. What you can do is that capture the value of the response object and then try to have some operation on it (.then()). Please follow the code below,

```
fetch('someurl').then(respose) => {
    let somedata = response.json(); // as you will capture the json response, body will not be locked anymore. 
    somedata.then(data) => {
        {
             error handling (if (data.err) { ---- })
        }
        {
             operations (else { ---- })
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using **Live Server** on VSC? It may be the culprit.

In a similar situation, I reverted to Apache to serve static content and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i hade the same issue in react js when iam tried to fetch data with reduxjs/toolkit in Slice....

**Code was**

```
export function getProducts() {
return async function getProductsThunk(dispatch, getState) {
    const data = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
    const result =data.json()
    dispatch(fetchProducts(result))
}}
```

**Error in Console Show**

[image]

so as you can see on the error shows, data returned as Promise

**How to Fix **

```
export function getProducts() {
return async function getProductsThunk(dispatch, getState) {
    const data = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
    const result = await data.json() //add await before convert to json
    dispatch(fetchProducts(result))
}}
```

Comment: That's not the same error though, is it? Original error was `body stream is locked`