# Why does logging the result of fetch() "break" it ("body stream is locked")?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

In trying to understand a return result, I ended up with this simple thing:

```
    fetch('http://localhost:8081/position', {mode: 'cors'})
        .then(response => {return response.json()})
        .then(result => console.log(result));
```

which works - it prints the json of the response.

But this does not work:

```
    fetch('http://localhost:8081/position', {mode: 'cors'})
        .then(response => {console.log(response.json()); return response.json();})
        .then(result => console.log(result));
```

It thows `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream is locked`

Why is that?

Comment: It's not about logging it, it's about calling `.json()`

Comment: **See Also**: [Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53511974/1366033)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The promise does not really break, but the problem is that `.json()` (and `.body()`, `.text()`) may only be called once.

The HTTP request is modeled as a stream, and you can't really read from a stream twice.

However, you can put the result of the `.json()` promise in a variable, and return that instead.

```
fetch('http://localhost:8081/position', {mode: 'cors'})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(jsonBody => { console.log(jsonBody); return jsonBody; })
    .then(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: Lightglobe :)   Reassuringly,  `.then(response => {let r = response.json(); console.log(r); return(r)})` does what I expected.  Thanks!

Comment: @GreenAsJade subtle suggestion. `const` is always better than `let` if you situation doesn't require `let`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I just typed some characters there to make the debugging compile, maybe I should get in the habit of consting always!

Comment: Yah what I basically do is use `const` by default until I do something that causes (in my case) typescript to complain ;)