# How do I make the output of this Javascript API response global?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to receive the output for the following code where the cc variable would log a value into the empty global country variable. Afterwards print it to the console, however it isn't working. How would I make the local variable cc here to global/give the global variable country a value?

```js
var country = '';
fetch('https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/')
.then( res => res.json())
.then(response => {
    var cc = (response.countryCode);
    country = cc;
 });
 console.log(country);
```

Comment: are you sure your getting value `var cc = (response.countryCode)` here? make `console.log(cc)` after `var cc = (response.countryCode)`. your code looks correct

Comment: Yes I am getting the cc value on console if I try. However, I want to use this value globally for latter part of the code within the country variable. How would I achieve that?

Comment: why do you need to make it global. run all the code that depends country code once the request gets resolved.

Comment: Because it is within the client side part. It will be used in later localization problem for targeted content delivery.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your problem has to do with the asynchronous nature of your code. Let me explain.

```js
var country = '';
fetch('https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/')
    .then( res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
        var cc = (response.countryCode);
        country = cc;
    });
console.log(country);
```

The fetch function is asynchronous. That's why you need the `.then` methods. This means that while the fetch function runs, JavaScript doesn't stop the rest of the program, and instead moves on while `fetch()` runs in the background. Hence, when you `console.log(country)`, it's still of the original value (empty string).

To answer your question, you can use `Promise`s to log the value of cc.

```js
var country = '';
const fetchPromise = fetch('https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/')
    .then( res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
        var cc = (response.countryCode);
        country = cc;
    });

Promise.resolve(fetchPromise) // Waits for fetchPromise to get its value
    .then(() => console.log(country))
```

You can find out more about promises at the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks for the fix. it yes indeed passes the value of cc to country however, I still can't use it globally. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your currently call `console.log(country)` before `country` is set to `response.countryCode`.

You could solve this by placing your code inside an async [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) in the following manner:

```js
(async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/');
  const ipData   = await response.json();
  const country  = ipData.countryCode;

  // place all code that uses `country` in here
  console.log(country);
})();
```

---

If you have another script with function definitions that depends on `county` be sure to accept it as parameter and don't pull the data from a global variable.

```
// helper_functions.js

// Bad
function someFunctionThatUsesCountry() {
  console.log(country); // <- don't expect the global to be set
}

// Good
function someFunctionThatUsesCountry(country) {
  console.log(country); // pull country ^ from the parameter list
}
```

You can then call you other script inside the IIFE by just passing the value.

```
(async () => {
  // ...
  someFunctionThatUsesCountry(country);
})();
```

---

If for some reason want a global variable really bad. You should place the promise inside this variable, not the value. With this promise you can pass the value, as well as notify other scripts when this value is available.

```
// script_1.js
window.country = fetch('https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/')
                 .then(response => response.json())
                 .then(ipData => ipData.countryCode);
```

```
// script_2.js (must be loaded after script_1.js)
window.country.then(country => { // <- wait until country is available
  // do stuff with country
  console.log(country);
});
```

Comment: Hi! but the issue is that it can't be placed within this! I need to somehow make country a globally reusable variable. Could you kindly suggest any solution for that?

Comment: @Ali I've added two suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem come from the fact that your fetch is an asynchrone function, with a promise.

What you want to do is that (I suppose)

```
var country = '';
//then
fetch('https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/')
.then( res => res.json())
.then(response => {
    var cc = (response.countryCode);
    country = cc;
 });
//then
console.log(country);
```

But, since you use an async function, this is what is done:

```
//first
var country = '';
//second
fetch('https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/')
.then( res => res.json())
.then(response => {
    //fourth
    var cc = (response.countryCode);
    country = cc;
 });
//third
console.log(country);
```

How to fix that? it depend. If your console.log is triggered by a button, make it wait for country to be filled

else, put your code in the last then, or use `Promise.all()` (documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise/all))

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` is happening before `fetch` is resolved. Try this:

```
let country = '';
fetch('https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => country = res.countryCode)
    .then(() => console.log(country))
```

Comment: Hi Ulou! Thanks for the solution. However, it still doesn't make country a globally reusable variable. Would there be a way to do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` returns a `Promise`, hence the `.then()` chain in your question.

But if you stepped into Promise Land, you won't find out. You'll have to do everything with Promises.

But you might split you logic into small manageable parts like here

```js
console.clear()

let cached = null;
const lookup         = ()          => fetch('https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/');
// Caching json and not the fetch promise, because
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/54731385/476951
const getJson        = ()          => cached = cached || lookup() .then(response => response.json());
const getParameter   = (parameter) => getJson()                   .then(json => json[parameter]);
const getCountry     = ()          => getParameter('country')     .then(value => value);
const getCountryCode = ()          => getParameter('countryCode') .then(value => value);


getCountryCode().then(countryCode => {
  console.log('countryCode:', countryCode)
})

getCountry().then(country => {
  console.log('country:', country)
})

getParameter('city').then(city => {
  console.log('city:', city)
})
```