# loging the response.json() inside the then() method before returning the response.json() promise

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm learning web development so maybe the question is already asked but I haven't found it.
I tried to log `response.json()` inside the `.then` method before returning the `response.json()` promise to the second `.then` handler function. The problem I'm facing is that although the `response.json()`'s result is being logged, the code in the next `.then` method is not being executed.
Here's my code:

```js
const fetchPromise = fetch('https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/apis/fetching-data/can-store/products.json');

console.log(fetchPromise)
    
fetchPromise
.then( response => {
  console.log(response.json())
  return response.json();
})
.then( json => {
  console.log(json[0].name);
});
```

The code is supposed to log `response.json()`'s result and then end with logging `"baked beans"` in the second `.then` handler, but it just logs the promise object and nothing happens afterwards.
This code, however, seems to work:

```js
const fetchPromise = fetch('https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/apis/fetching-data/can-store/products.json');
console.log(fetchPromise)
    
fetchPromise
.then( response => {
  var resp=response.json() // save the value first
  console.log(resp)
  return resp
})
.then( json => {
  console.log(json[0].name);
});
```

So why does storing the result in a variable work, but directly calling it doesn't?

Comment: `I tired to log response.json()` or `I tryed to log response.json()` ?

Comment: It's `tried` :)

Answer (score 4):

In the console, you'll see this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream already read
```

That's because you [cannot execute response.json() twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53511974/javascript-fetch-failed-to-execute-json-on-response-body-stream-is-locked).
Simply move the console.log down to the last `.then` and log `json` instead of `res.json`:

```js
fetchPromise
.then( response => {
  console.log(response.json()) // remove this line
  return response.json()
})
.then( json => {
  console.log(json); // add this line
  console.log(json[0].name);
});
```